# What is the recommended procedure to report potential vulnerabilities in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, bug, vulnerability

I was browsing etherscan's verified smart contracts (i.e. the ones with the source code attached), and I saw that one of the smart contracts contain (or at least I think it contains) a potential vulnerability, in particular it may burn some money. It is sufficient to leave a comment in the comment section?

In this case may be sufficient, but if the vulnerability was even worse? Is there the possibility to contact the developers?

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, there's nothing you can do. The code is immutable and it will stay like that forever.

Socially, there's a lot which can be done. In most cases, a comment should be enough, indeed. However, if you reckon that's a high-volume contract with many daily active users, contact [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/contactus), [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) and alert the [Reddit](https://reddit.com/r/ethereum) community. If it's more serious, get in touch with the Ethereum Foundation or even the White Hat Group.